# Hibernate @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY) @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) always fetched eagerly

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping, byte-code-enhancement

My goal is to enable lazy loading for a bidirectional ono-to-one association on the parent-side of the association. Consider the following two entities:

Parent `Vendor.java`:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Vendor extends User {

    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "vendor", optional = false, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Operator operator;

}
```

Child `Operator.java`:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Operator {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Vendor vendor;

}
```

**Note:** I omitted other fields, constructors and equals/hashCode functions for brevity.

As mentioned before, my goal is to load the vendor's operator lazyly. Therefore following the [Hibernate user guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional-lazy) and [Vlad Mihalcea's tutorial on how to enable bytecode enhancement in Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-enable-bytecode-enhancement-dirty-checking-in-hibernate/), I annotated the parent-side association with `@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)` in addtion to the `@OneToOne` with `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`. After adding the following plugin to my `pom.xml`, the operator is still loaded eagerly upon fetching the vendor.

Plugin configuration:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <configuration>
              <failOnError>true</failOnError>
              <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
              <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
              <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

When I fetch a vendor, the following SQL is generated:

```
2019-10-18 13:43:16.138  INFO 12212 --- [           main] n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener      : 
Name:dataSource, Connection:8, Time:2, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["select vendor0_.id as id1_39_0_, vendor0_1_.created_at as created_2_39_0_, vendor0_1_.version as version3_39_0_, vendor0_1_.account_non_locked as account_4_39_0_, vendor0_1_.email as email5_39_0_, vendor0_1_.email_verified as email_ve6_39_0_, vendor0_1_.enabled as enabled7_39_0_, vendor0_1_.last_password_reset_date as last_pas8_39_0_, vendor0_1_.password as password9_39_0_, vendor0_.address_district as address_1_43_0_, vendor0_.address_latitude as address_2_43_0_, vendor0_.address_longitude as address_3_43_0_, vendor0_.address_city as address_4_43_0_, vendor0_.address_country_code as address_5_43_0_, vendor0_.address_street as address_6_43_0_, vendor0_.address_street_no as address_7_43_0_, vendor0_.address_zip_code as address_8_43_0_, vendor0_.contact_details_email as contact_9_43_0_, vendor0_.contact_details_phone as contact10_43_0_, vendor0_.customer_no_customer_no as custome17_43_0_, vendor0_.description as descrip11_43_0_, vendor0_.hidden as hidden12_43_0_, vendor0_.name as name13_43_0_, vendor0_.slug as slug14_43_0_, vendor0_.verified as verifie15_43_0_ from vendor vendor0_ inner join users vendor0_1_ on vendor0_.id=vendor0_1_.id where vendor0_.id=?"]
Params:[(4)]

2019-10-18 13:43:16.141  INFO 12212 --- [           main] n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener      : 
Name:dataSource, Connection:8, Time:1, Success:True
Type:Prepared, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["select operator0_.id as id1_17_0_, operator0_.address_city as address_2_17_0_, operator0_.address_country_code as address_3_17_0_, operator0_.address_street as address_4_17_0_, operator0_.address_street_no as address_5_17_0_, operator0_.address_zip_code as address_6_17_0_, operator0_.bank_account_bic as bank_acc7_17_0_, operator0_.bank_account_iban as bank_acc8_17_0_, operator0_.bank_account_owner as bank_acc9_17_0_, operator0_.company as company10_17_0_, operator0_.contact_details_email as contact11_17_0_, operator0_.contact_details_phone as contact12_17_0_, operator0_.contact_person_first_name as contact13_17_0_, operator0_.contact_person_gender as contact14_17_0_, operator0_.contact_person_last_name as contact15_17_0_, operator0_.tax_id as tax_id16_17_0_, operator0_.vat_id as vat_id17_17_0_ from operator operator0_ where operator0_.id=?"]
Params:[(4)]
```

When I comment out the operator field in `Vendor.java`, only the first statement is generated. I also tried setting the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer` property as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41127248/5151202), but it didn't change the generated SQL. My apprehension is that this issue might be related to the mapping with `@MapsId` in `Operator.java` as this is not used in the [Hibernate example](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional-lazy).

Version of used frameworks:
Spring Boot `2.1.9.RELEASE`
Hibernate `5.3.12.Final`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was to place the `hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin` to early in the plugin list of the `<build>` part in the `pom.xml`, namely before the `maven-compiler-plugin`. After placing it at the end of the `<plugins>` list, it worked as expected.